# Returning the first model from a hasMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to create a quick method to return the first model from a one-to-many relationship? Here is my code, from the model file:

```
public function books() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
}

public function first_book() {
    return $this->book()->first();
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()
```

The reason I want to use this is so that I can collect the first record using the with() method, for example:

```
$authors = Author::with('first_book')->select('*');
```

I'm using these records with Datatables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With laravel 9.x you can use the `latestOfMany` or `oldestOfMany` like so;

```php
// your relationship
public function books() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
}

// Get the first inserted child model
public function first_book() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Book')->oldestOfMany();

}

// Get the last inserted child model
public function last_book() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Book')->latestOfMany();

}
```

**BONUS:** If you are on php 5.5 or later, you can get the fully qualified class name by using the scope resolution operator, looks clean, ie;

```php
// your relationship
public function books() {
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}

// Get the first inserted child model
public function first_book() {
   return $this->hasOne(Book::class)->oldestOfMany();

}

// Get the last inserted child model
public function last_book() {
   return $this->hasOne(Book::class)->latestOfMany();

}
```

[Link to the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

Answer (score 57):

I might be late but for your future use and for other who want the same output try this one -

// If you need the last one

```
public function books() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Book')->latest();
}
```

// If you need the first entry -

```
public function books() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Book')->oldest();
    }
```

Comment: It's order by ID right? How to get it from where and custom orderBy?

Comment: In my case debugbar revealed that all the related models were being hydrated even though the relationship was hasOne. Adding take(1) significantly reduced the memory load and reduced the request duration significantly

Comment: this does not return 1 data, it returns everything.

Comment: @JenuelGanawed Can you please share you code? You have hasOne relation there, it should return a singe record.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur I think it defaults to `created_at`. You can pass a field name into the `latest` and `oldest` functions to customize.

Answer (score 15):

A relation that can be eager loaded has to return a query. The `first()` function returns an eloquent object.

The solution is to limit the number of results of this query like so:

```
public function first_book() {
    return $this->books()->take(1);
}
```

`$author->first_book` will still be a collection, but it will only contain the first related book in your database.

Comment: This answer is wrong, if you debug the sql statments that eloquent executes, you'll see that  when you use the 'with' method, you are only getting the last element of ALL the collections because of the take(1).

Answer (score 8):

To use `with()` your method has to return a collection from a relation method, because your relation is hasMany. So what you could do is:

```
public function books() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
}

public function first_book() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book')->limit(1);
}
```

Which would return a collection with your first item, so you' still have to call `first()`:

```
$authors = Author::with('first_book')->select('*');
$authors->first_book->first();
```

Comment: I would replace return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book')->limit(1); with return $this->books()->limit(1);

Comment: Is it possible to return a value from a particular index location? For example, like this .....      $row->sub_category[0]->name

Comment: @RoshJ depends what is `sub_category`, if its a collection then yes, you can call `$row->sub_category->get(0)->name`.

Comment: yes,subcategory is an array, but this is not working, i tried :(

Comment: this doesnt work,, it only returns 1 data on first Author, but doesnt return data on second author.

Answer (score 3):

A one-to-one relationship is a very basic relation. For example

```
public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Book');
    }
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you want it to return an object rather than an array.  If you use `take(1)` as shown above, then you'll end up having to always run `first()` or `[0]` to get the data you want.

Comment: Very good solution, also we can chain query conditions to get the desired record.

Comment: Only then should the relation be called - book

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but in case someone is looking for a quicker way to do this without modifying your Model class. You can grab the first record of a relationship directly from the Model hasMany relationship.

I have used this and it works well. For example if you have a hasMany relationship between `Library` and `Books` model;

```
$first_book = $library->books->first();
```

or to get the last book;

```
$last_book = $library->books->last();
```