# How to highlight displaying records acording to values of table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using `Laravel 5.6` and `mysql` for my web application. in My application I have table named as `vehicles` as following,

```
id   name   number   adtype   
----------------------------
1   car     123     1
2   van     256     0
3   car     248     0
4   van     159     1
5   car     158     1
etc
```

and I am displaying above data on `VehicleController` as following

```
public function index(){
    $vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')->get();
    return view('vehicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
}
```

upload is related table witch contain images of the vehicles

and My `index.blade.php` is like this

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
 @forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )
     @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
     <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
     @php
     $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
     @endphp
     <div style="border-style: solid; color: black; ">
         <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>
     @endif
</div>
```

it is working fine. but now I need highlight ads which related to adtype value as 1 from the `vechicles` table. how can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I get your question right, but where's the problem of just using an if to determine if `adtype` equals `1` and handle the `div`'s class or style attribute differently?

```
<div style="color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'black' : 'blue' }}">
```

Besides that: You shouldn't lazy load something in a template; that's not the purpose of the template, this is a task for the controller. Use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) with a [proper relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271432/8394877) instead.

Note: You can - or should - also [type cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) attributes to equal their original purpose and prevent misleading comparisons.

In your case `adtype` looks like a boolean, so you would add this to your model's `$cast` property:

```
'adtype' => 'boolean',
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
    @forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )


    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
    <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
        @php
        $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
        @endphp
        @if($vehicule->adtype == 1)
        <div style="border-style: solid; color: black; ">
            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>
        </div>
         @else
        <div style="border-style: solid; color: blue; ">
            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: occured this error msg **syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)**

Comment: now got this **syntax error, unexpected end of file**

Comment: check your closing `div` the div should have closing element

Comment: A missing closing tag does not create a syntax error.

Comment: Copy the whole block and try again

Comment: In this case, the `@endforelse` is missing and a closing `</a>` before the last `@endif`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all of your code, but you are going to want something like this:

In your css:

```
<style>
.highlight {
   ... whatever ...
}
</style>
```

And then, in your blade,

```
@if( $vehicule->adtype == 1 )
<span class="highlight"> ...... whatever ..... </span>
@endif
```

Or, if you want it inline,

```
<span class="{{ ($vehicule->adtype == 1) ? 'highlight' : '' }}">
```