# Laravel select one image from every row from database

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my database , one with cars and one with images for cars..is a one to many relationship..A car can have multiple images , but I want to select for every car just one image. The 2 tables are
Car table:

```
 Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('model');
        $table->integer('seats');
        $table->string('fuel');
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('gearbox');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('coinType');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Images table:

    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->integer('car_id');
                $table->string('file_name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });

    class Car extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'model',
        'seats',
        'fuel',
        'year',
        'color',
        'gearbox',
        'price',
        'coinType',
    ];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }


Image model:


    class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'car_id',
        'file_name'
    ];
    
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
```

I tried to make a join between tables like that:

```
$images = Image::join('cars', 'images.car_id', '=', 'car.id')
    ->select('images.file_name')
    ->first();
```

But I get only the first row from that table. I need some help here, Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning the first model from a hasMany relationship in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524888/returning-the-first-model-from-a-hasmany-relationship-in-laravel)

Comment: Your question is tagged eloquent, but you aren't using eloquent. Set up your relationships as in the answers to the duplicate question.